# function_exists() not working codeigniter

Tags: php, function

I am trying to check if a function exist and do the processing.

I check this by:

```
if(function_exists("create_offerlovit_template_data"))
{
    echo "function exists";
}
else
{
    echo "function not exists";
}
```

I have the function:

```
public function create_offerlovit_template_data($update,$shop_id)
{

}
```

The function exists but always prints 'function not exists'. Why is this happening? How do I properly use `function_exists`.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/82837/#416766

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php .

function_exists is for functions only.

Example:

```
method_exists($instance, "create_offerlovit_template_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

`public function create_offerlovit_template_data($update,$shop_id){}`

This looks like a class method and not a "stand alone"? function (bad terminology there I know),

I believe you're looking for this [`method_exists`](http://php.net/method_exists)

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the existence of a function, but "public function" - is a method.
Use "method_exists()".

Answer (score 0):

For checking if a particular method exists in some object, try to use method_exists() function:

Resource([link](http://php.net/method_exists))

you could try

```
 if (method_exists($this,$method)) {
            // if true
        } else {
            // if false
        }
```